# Segmentation fault when using QWidget.show() method on pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to run some PyQt5 examples from internet. However, they always end in segmentation fault when running the QWidget.show() method. I don't think there are errors in the code as they are taken from internet tutorials. All other commands seem to work fine. Below is an example of code crashing at the show method.

```
  import sys
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)

      w = QWidget()
      w.resize(250, 150)
      w.move(300, 300)
      w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
      w.show()

      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Maybe there is some issue in my pyqt5 installation? Did anyone have a similar problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain how you installed pyqt5

Comment: I run

        'pip3 install PyQt5'

Before that, I have installed standard qt using the installer from the official website.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: You could uninstall PyQt5 with: `sudo pip3 uninstall PyQt5` And install it from the ubuntu repository `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`

Comment: Still gives me a segmentation fault. Curiously, I just find out that the code works fine with python 2.7. Until now I was only testing with the 3.6 version.

Comment: @Leafar. Whenever possible, you should always use the official packages supplied by your distro for python, sip, pyqt and qt. Don't try to mix-and-match installation methods unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Do you see any warning other than the segfault when you run it in a terminal?

Comment: No, there are no warnings. Just a segmentation fault when running that instruction.